# Replacement/porting of memset to C++ from C

Tags: c++, port, porting, memset

I want to port C calls from a C example to a C++ example. But I'm not sure what is the right way to do this. In the memset part, what should I replace for the C++ code?

```
static int begin_request_handler(struct mg_connection *conn) {

  return 1;
}



struct mg_callbacks {
  int  (*begin_request)(struct mg_connection *);
  void (*end_request)(const struct mg_connection *, int reply_status_code);
  int  (*log_message)(const struct mg_connection *, const char *message);
  int  (*init_ssl)(void *ssl_context);
  int (*websocket_connect)(const struct mg_connection *);
  void (*websocket_ready)(struct mg_connection *);
  int  (*websocket_data)(struct mg_connection *);
  const char * (*open_file)(const struct mg_connection *,
                             const char *path, size_t *data_len);
  void (*init_lua)(struct mg_connection *, void *lua_context);
  void (*upload)(struct mg_connection *, const char *file_name);
};



struct mg_callbacks callbacks;
memset(&callbacks, 0, sizeof(callbacks)); 
callbacks.begin_request = begin_request_handler;
```

How should memset look like if I call it from C++?

Comment: What's wrong with what you've got?

Comment: is it the right way to do this , this si basically my question

Answer (score 3):

Ok, so the way I would so this is:

```
struct mg_callbacks callbacks = { };
```

That will fill it with zero values.

But `memset` is perfectly fine - C++ is designed to take C code with little or no modification, so if you don't NEED to change something, then I don't see a real reason to change the code.

You could of course also declare a constructor in `mg_callbacks` that sets each of the pointers to `NULL`, e.g.

```
struct mg_callbacks 
{
   mg_callbacks()
   {
      begin_request = NULL;
      ...
   }
   ... 
};
```

This will GUARANTEE that no code forgets the "memset".

Of course this whole structure seems like it should be a baseclass with virtual functions that are then implemented specifically for whatever different purposes you have in a derived class. But that's nothing to do with the use of `memset` as such.

Comment: Solid technical advice in this answer. I would add that perhaps what OP should do is define a default constructor which 0-initializes all the members of the struct, and then `mg_callbacks callbacks; // is initialized`. Note that in C++, you can leave off the `struct` when declaring variables.

Comment: Edited with that included.

Answer (score 0):

You can use memset in C++ if you want, but if you are after the idiomatic C++ method of setting a block of memory then what you want is std::fill.

Comment: `std::fill` is for filling a sequence of objects. You couldn't use it to zero the bytes of a class's representation like this without some horrible pointer casts.